# Syntax error in if statement

Tags: bash, if-statement, syntax-error

SYNTAX:

```
while read l
do
    export filename=$l
    if [[ `echo $filename | sed -n 's:TEST.*/TEST:&:p'` -ne 0 ]];
    then
        echo "both are same : $filename"
    else
        echo "diff: $filename"
    fi
done < scripts2.txt*
```

Problem: Normally its working fine. But for the below data it throws syntax error...

```
<TEST><![BIGDATA[$EXECUTE SCRIPT ON ALL SERVER $WELCOME#]]></TEST>
```

Pls let me know what was the exact problem is????

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Where is the below data?

Comment: Sorry, but that's full of errors, no data is attached and it is not self-explaining about what you want to do. And please list your actual script (I suspect this is it not)

Comment: The data was hidden since it looked like HTML formatting.  I re-formatted the question to make it visible.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, don't try to parse XML/HTML with regular expressions.  XML is not a [regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), and you will run into an endless stream of problems.  What is it that you are ultimately trying to do?  There's probably an easier way to approach the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand what you wish to perform. The obvious mistake in the code above is that you are trying to make an arithmetic comparison (`-ne`) with something that is not a number.

Your `echo ... | sed ...` expression for the input above, should produce the string "`<&>`" and you are testing if this is not equal to zero.

Again, clarifying your intentions would enable other to help you.